# Performance of Delete then Insert vs Merge in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, database-performance

I have a SQL Server 2008 query which looks like this

```
Delete from Table1

INSERT INTO TABLE1
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

And I would like to improve the performance of this query by some means.

So, would be a nice approach to replace the `Delete and Insert` query with `Merge` statement which handles `Delete, Update and Insert` in one single batch.

Please advice if any other way exist through which i can improve the performance of query.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the best way to test the performance is for the OP to test it themselves... any test will be more accurate on your own systems.

Comment: Can't I ask questions related to the best practices while writing queries in sql server.

Comment: Sure - but the answer is almost always "it depends". It depends on your schema, your data, how you're using it, and your particular situation. What may be best for you may not be best for someone else.

Comment: As always with performance questions, it depends. How big are the tables? Separate delete, update and inserts could be quicker on big tables with correct indexes. Just deleting everything at the start could be very slow...

Answer (score 1):

When you compare query profile statistic of using merge command and using insert and deleted command pay attention that merge command have better performance because number of insert, update,delete and select statement also number of transaction is lower in merge command. Also amount of DTS package is lower in merge command.